# Can not find variable in scope Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am very new to swift ui and I got this compiling error when making a war card game
"Cannot find 'playerScore' in scope"

I'm not sure why but I'm sure it's such an obvious thing

here is my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // used state keywor
    @State var playerCard = "card7"
    @State var cpuCard = "card13"
    
    @State var playerScore = 0
    @State var cpuScore = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Image("background-wood-grain")
                .resizable()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                EditButton().position(x: 330, y: 20)
                }
                Image("logo")
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Image(playerCard)
                    Spacer()
                    Image(cpuCard)
                    Spacer()
                   
                   
                }
                Spacer()
                
                

                
                Button {
                    deal()
                } label: {
                    Image("button")
                }
                
              
                
                Spacer()
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("Players")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bottom, 10.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                   // Look at how we turned a function into a string here v
                        //that way we can use it with a text attribute
                        Text(String(playerScore))
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
               
                    Spacer()
                    VStack{
                        Text("CPU")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .padding(.bottom, 10.0)
                        Text(String(cpuScore))
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                   
                
                    Spacer()
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
               Spacer()
            }
           
        }
       
    }
    
    func deal(){
        //Randomize the players card
        var playerCardValue = Int.random(in: 2...14)
        playerCard = "card" + String(playerCardValue)
        //Randomize the cpus card
        var cpuCardValue = Int.random(in: 2...14)
        cpuCard = "card" + String(cpuCardValue)
        // Update the score
        if playerCardValue > cpuCardValue{
            // add 1 to player score
            playerScore += 1
        }
        else if cpuCardValue > playerCardValue{
            // Add 1 to cpu score
            cpuScore += 1
        }
    // nothing for tie because nothing would change duhh
    }


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

It worked fine until I think I changed one thing and now it's showing erorrs. I dont really know where to start in fixing this so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to move `deal` _inside_ `ContentView`. Right now it's outside the `struct`. This might be more clear if you use `ctrl-i` to format your code, which will show the indentation difference between the two.

Comment: Just put deal() function inside your struct